# Count the number of occurences of binary data

Tags: linux, binary, grep

I need to count the occurrences of the hex string `0xFF 0x84 0x03 0x07` in a binary file, without too much hassle... is there a quick way of grepping for this data from the linux command line or should I write dedicated code to do it?

Answer (score 8):

#### Patterns without linebreaks

If your version of `grep` takes the `-P` parameter, then you can use `grep -a -P`, to search for an arbitrary binary string (with no linebreaks) inside a binary file.  This is close to what you want:

```
grep -a -c -P '\xFF\x84\x03\x07' myfile.bin
```

- `-a` ensures that binary files will not be skipped
- `-c` outputs the count
- `-P` specifies that your pattern is a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE), which allows strings to contain hex characters in the above `\xNN` format.

Unfortunately, `grep -c` will only count the number of "lines" the pattern appears on - not actual occurrences.

To get the exact number of occurrences with `grep`, it seems you need to do:

```
grep -a -o -P '\xFF\x84\x03\x07' myfile.bin | wc -l
```

`grep -o` separates out each match onto its own line, and `wc -l` counts the lines.

#### Patterns containing linebreaks

If you do need to grep for linebreaks, one workaround I can think of is to use `tr` to swap the character for another one that's not in your search term.

```
# set up test file (0a is newline)
xxd -r <<< '0:08 09 0a 0b 0c 0a 0b 0c' > test.bin

# grep for '\xa\xb\xc' doesn't work
grep -a -o -P '\xa\xb\xc' test.bin | wc -l

# swap newline with oct 42 and grep for that
tr '\n\042' '\042\n' < test.bin | grep -a -o -P '\042\xb\xc' | wc -l
```

(Note that 042 octal is the double quote `"` sign in [ASCII](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Ezyu/ascii.html).)

Another way, if your string doesn't contain Nulls (`0x0`), would be to use the [`-z`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#:%7E:text=%2Dz%2C%20%2D%2Dnull%2Ddata) flag, and swap Nulls for linebreaks before passing to `wc`.

```
grep -a -o -P -z '\xa\xb\xc' test.bin | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | wc -l
```

(Note that `-z` and `-P` may be [experimental](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#:%7E:text=%2DP%2C%20%2D%2Dperl%2Dregexp) in conjunction with each other.  But with simple expressions and no Nulls, I would guess it's fine.)

Comment: I'll note that this wasn't working for me, but I figured it out... based on my locale settings, it was treating the input as UTF-8, and not finding my pattern, which would have been an invalid character in UTF-8.  setting either `LANG` or `LC_ALL` to `C` made it work, though.  i.e. doing this: `LANG=C grep -a -o -P ... | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

use hexdump like

`hexdump -v -e '"0x" 1/1 "%02X" " "' <filename> | grep -oh "0xFF 0x84 0x03 0x07" |wc -w`

`hexdump` will output binary file in the given format like 0xNN

`grep` will find all the occurrences of the string without considering the same ones repeated on a line

`wc` will give you final count

Answer (score 0):

did you try `grep -a`?

from grep man page:

```
-a, --text
              Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ hexdump a.out | grep -Ec 'ff ?84 ?03 ?07'
```

Comment: My `hexdump` (by default) wraps the lines, prepends an offset to each line, and swaps the endian of byte pairs.  This format makes it a real challenge for grep to catch all cases, while still avoiding false positives with the offset.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but does solve the problem when the search string is ASCII but the file is binary:

```
cat binaryfile | sed 's/SearchString/SearchString\n/g' | grep -c SearchString
```

Basically, 'grep' was almost there except it only counted one occurrence if there was no newline byte in between, so I added the newline bytes.